# some problems about c++ try catch

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I have a question about try catch mechanism. like code:

```
  global value default 0;
  int thread1()
  {
       try
       {
           set global value to 1;
           if exception happens
           {
               jump into catch;
           }
           set global value to 0;
       }
       catch 
       {
           ......
       }
  }
  int thread2()
  {
       ASSERT(global value = 0);
   }
```

If I have the fake code as shown, in try block I set a global value to 1 and then an exception happens, in thread2 I have a ASSERT to test if this global value is equal to 0, then thread2 will failed explicitly because in thread1, we jump into the catch block because of an exception. So can anybody give me some explanation ? I don't know how try--catch works to prevent this.

Comment: I assume the code you show is *pseudo* code? Also note that C, C++ and C# are totally different languages with their own semantics when it comes to exceptions and exception handling. Heck, C doesn't even *have* exceptions.

Comment: Also please take into account that the set and read operations on the global value have to be atomic.

Comment: You want to know how to ensure some code is run (`global_value=0;`) even if an exception is thrown? [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: If you want to set it to `0` in any case, put it after the tey/catch. But maybe your logic is wrong. Tell us why you want to do something like this, like "how to prevent one thread from runing when another one fails".

Comment: how you can check if exception happens in  try part?

Comment: @RAIL - BoBTFish  Yes, as you say.

Comment: what I want to know is how to recovery the stats if I set a global value before exception happens.

Comment: @Simon It's RAII, and it's a link, not a nickname.

Comment: @RAIL, Sorry. can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @SimonSu What "stats"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions are brutal break of the normal flow of execution. The error correcting flow is to find a catch that correspond to the object thrown; this may lead to several function calls reverse traversal. This is why it needs care to use them, you have two flow of execution : the normal one, and the error one.

If the exception thrown is catched by the catch-block directly after, then you just have to set your variable to 0 in the catch-block.

It not, a good solution is RAII (as suggested in comments). RAII is a very simple idea. As you know that every object created on stack at the entry of any block is destroyed when control leave the block, the idea is to build an object that encapsulate something, so that the destructor will be called whatever happens:

```
class GlobalControl {
  public:
    GlobalControl() { myglob = 1; } // RAII
    ~GlobalControl() { myglob = 0; } // RRID
};

... // somewhere else
try {
  GlobalControl c; // ctor call init glob to 1
  ...
} // whatever will happens, leaving this block cause a call to dtor of c
catch (...) {
}
```

RAII stands for Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, here your resource acquisition is to set your global to 1, and this is made in the initialization part of the object. RAII should be called RAIIRRID, RAII + Resource Releasing Is Destruction (the resource release is to set your global to 0, and this is made in the destructor).